How to use the Python filemagic library to check the MIME type of a file for a file that is not in the same directory?
So, I am building a flask application where I currently need to check the MIME type of file to restrict the type of files to be uploaded (not being limited to the extension of the files).
The folder structure is like :
Folder
...uploads
...app.py
...packages
I am currently applying the logic on a file inside packages and importing it in app.py.
So I keep encountering errors while doing so.
This is the method inside package using the filemagic library
def check_mime(filename):
    path=os.path.join('./uploads',filename)
    mime_type= magic.from_file(path,mime=True) 
   
   
    allowed_mimetypes={'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document','application/pdf','text/plain'}
    return mime_type in allowed_mimetypes

Error Tracebacks

Please provide a [mre] and the errors, i.e. complete traceback(s)

Filenames are interpreted relative to the current directory.  You seem to be assuming that the current directory is the same as the directory where the python script itself is located, but evidently it is not.  You can use import os; print(os.getcwd()) to display the actual current directory.

Sorry I have gotten the logic completely wrong,i need to check the mime of the file before it gets uploaded.
